# Why the pipe command can not work

Tags: shell

```
firefox $(grep -l "mysed" /home/test)
```

the command can open all my file which contain the word  `mysed`  in firefox,when i change the command into the following,

```
grep -l "mysed" /home/test |  firefox
```

why the firefox can not open the files selected by grep?

Answer (score 3):

Because a pipe doesn't apply parameters. A pipe redirects stdout from one process to stdin of another.

You can use `xargs` to achieve what you want:

```
grep -l "mysed" /home/test | xargs firefox
```

Answer (score 0):

The first command provides the files to be opened as command line arguments to Firefox whereas the second command provids them on the STDIN of Firefox doesnt interpret and so cannot open them.